How to remove several values from a multi picklist in the Salesforce flow?
I learned how to remove a value from the multi-picklist in the Salesforce flow. However, I struggle to remove more than one value from the MSP.
For instance,  I have A, B, and C three values selected in my MSP and I need to remove all of them, leave the field blank (no value). How can I achieve this task? Thank you

You may have seen this already, but I believe it's not possible with a simple Update element, per the info in the link below, under "Functional Limitations for Multi-Select Custom Picklists" -
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.picklist_limitations.htm&type=5

Did you try an assignment operator to set field to NULL?  Otherwise, UnofficalSf.com Multi-Select Picklist Magic is worth knowing about

@cropredy@Miguel Diaz, thanks for the links. They are very helpful. I used an Update element to set the picklist field to "None" (Empty) using $GlobalConstant.EmptyString and it worked! Wiped out all the selected values, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

as a service to the community, you should post your action as an answer; after 48 hours, you can mark it "accepted" and then other will know when searching that they'll get an answer as well

Using an Update element to set the multi-picklist field to "None" (Empty) using $GlobalConstant.EmptyString and it worked! It successfully wiped out all the selected values.

To clear all values from a multi-picklist field:
Create a Text Variable:
Set it to blank (no values).
Use an Assignment Element:
Assign the blank variable to the multi-picklist field.
Save and Activate the Flow. This will remove all selected values and leave the multi-picklist field blank.
